# Understanding string to binary Functions

Tags: python-3.x

```
def text_to_bits(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    bits = bin(int.from_bytes(text.encode(encoding, errors), 'big'))[2:] #<-------|
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8)) #<------|

def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    n = int(bits, 2) ##<-------|
    return n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode(encoding, errors) or '\0' ##<-------|
```

I was askin if someone could explain to me those two functions as i know what it does(change from str to binary & reverse) but i don't understand what excatly he did in both secound & 3rd lines of both functions

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at it analytically:

- ***text***.encode(encoding, errors): this function encodes the **text** into a bytes data type
- *int.from_bytes(**...**, 'big'))*: takes the input from above and convert into an int data type; 'big' is an indication of bites order
  in the bytes data
- *bin(**...**)*: converts an integer into a binary number
- *[2:]*: is meant to remove the '0b' in the beginning of the former

then within the return:

- *len(bits)*: displays the lenght of the **bits**
- 8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8): will always give a nearest multiple of 8
  to the **bits**
- *bits.zfill(...)*: will fill the bits with zeros from the left side so that the full string is of lenght of the multiple of 8

In the second function:

- *int(bits,2)*: converts a string with binary into an integer data type; 2 indicates that the bits variable contains a binary
- *n.bit_length()*: returns how many bits are needed to store a given number
- *(n.bit_length() + 7) // 8*: return the number of bytes needed to store the number
- *n.to_bytes()*: convert the integer into a byte format accepted by the decode function
- *decode()* : converts the byte notation into a string ('utf-8' as specified)

The best way to understand the this chain of data manipulations will be if you just play with all the given functions one by one. Then it will surely make sense.